# Vue.js syntax not working

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have this code and if you look at it, it logically makes sense but it doesn't work. I spend almost 3hrs looking for an answer but since the tutorial I am following is different from the found solution, none of them worked. I'm a complete beginner in this and I'm crying blood over this. Is the code I have an outdated one?

```
<div v-bind:class="{alert: showAlert }"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: it's correct code, can you provide jsfiddle with problem? because I created jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/maxsinev/b3nf0hme/ and `v-bind` syntax works fine.